# How to find out which virtualisation technology is used on Linux VPS server?

Tags: debian, xen, openvz, vps

I have access to some Debian Linux vps servers, however I cannot access their controls panel directly: only server administrator himself can do that.

Is there any way to find out what visualization technology is used on server from inside VPS? I need it only to know which kernel header package should I install (xen, openvz or any other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several methods for detecting the virtualization technology are listed on http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/.  Among the suggestions, my preferred method is `dmidecode`:

- VMWare:

  ```
  # dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product'
  Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
  Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
  ```
- Microsoft VirtualPC:

  ```
  # dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product'
  Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
  Product Name: Virtual Machine
  ```
- QEMU or KVM:

  ```
  # dmidecode | egrep -i 'vendor'
  Vendor: QEMU
  ```
- Virtuozzo or OpenVZ:

  ```
  # dmidecode
  /dev/mem: Permission denied
  ```
- Xen:

  ```
  # dmidecode | grep -i domU
  Product Name: HVM domU
  ```

Comment: openvz (and I think Virtuozzo) creates a /proc/usr_beancounters - to refine the detection :-) (There could be other virtualisation techniques which disallow reading /dev/mem - I'm for example not sure about lxc / linux namespaces.